# Spinner displaying app package name +address

Tags: android, json

I made a custom spinner by extending the ArrayAdapter<> class :

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {
    Activity activity ;
    List<Category> mCategoriesList ;
    int itemResourceId ;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Activity activity , List<Category> CategoriesList,int itemResourceId){

        super(activity,itemResourceId,CategoriesList);
        this.activity=activity;
        this.mCategoriesList=CategoriesList;
        this.itemResourceId=itemResourceId;

    }

    public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent){
        View MyCustomLayout = convertView ;
        if(MyCustomLayout== null){
            LayoutInflater Inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            MyCustomLayout = Inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_layout,parent,false);

        }
        TextView FullN = MyCustomLayout.findViewById(R.id.CatSubCatName);
        ImageView ProfP = MyCustomLayout.findViewById(R.id.BloodyIcon);
        FullN.setText(mCategoriesList.get(position).getName());



        return MyCustomLayout ;
    }
}
```

the supplied mCategoriesList is obtained by parsing a jsonArray :

```
try {
    JSONArray liste = new JSONArray(response);
    for (int i=0;i<liste.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj = liste.getJSONObject(i);
        Category cat= new Category();
        cat.setName(obj.getString("name"));
        cat.setID(obj.getInt("ID_categorie"));
        mCategoriesList.add(cat);}}
        catch(Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and this is the XML code for the custom layout corresponding to the spinner :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/BloodyIcon"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/CatSubCatName"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Purple"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the Category class :

```
public class Category {
    private int ID ;
    private  String Name ;

    public Category(int ID ,String Name){
        this.ID=ID ;
        this.Name=Name ;
    }
    public Category(){

    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

The problem is that instead of a list of category names displayed when i click on the spinner , i get something like this : packagename.Category@(randomcharacters) ,however the selected item displays the name correctly , am i missing something here ?

[Spinner Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOt0Z.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is what java objects' `toString()` method print by default.

Make sure the name is parsed correctly by placing breakpoints in the appropriate locations

Comment: i did as you suggested , the name is parsed correctly , even the name value is correct when debugging the getView method inside the adpater , but for some reason the setText method is passing the wrong value !!

Comment: so, did you find the reason and fix the problem?

Comment: nope , can't put my finger on the cause of this weird behavior yet

Comment: a picture might help us know what exactly is the problem.
also, I can't see how such a problem is causing you this much trouble with the existence of `stepOver` and `stepInto` functions of the debugger.. you should be able to trace it back to whatever is giving you the weird output

Comment: like we said, in the picture, the spinner item texts are just `Category` objects printed via `toString()`.
If you want to fix the problem, then check the value of `getName()` method in this line `FullN.setText(mCategoriesList.get(position).getName());`. Place a breakpoint here and evaluate the expression in the debugger.
But if you just want to work around it for now, you can override `toString()` method of `Category` class and your problem should be gone. Though I advise against doing this.